# Trying to stop angular material input container with icon float inside dialog from resizing the dialog

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

just trying to build a simple login form with angular material ans so far i've got this:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Login">
<form name="loginForm">
    <md-toolbar layout="row" layout-padding layout-align="center center">
        <span class="md-toolbar-item md-headline">Login</span>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content layout-padding>
        <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
            <md-icon class="md-dark" aria-label="username">person</md-icon>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Username">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
            <md-icon class="md-dark" arial-label="password">lock</md-icon>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password">
        </md-input-container>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <div class="md-actions">
        <md-button aria-label="Cancel">Cancel</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-primary" aria-label="Login">Login</md-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

which produces this:

[image: Basic login form untouched. Good enough]

Now when I turn the password input active, and the little label floats up, it's resizing the entire dialog and pushing the username field up. It's a small gripe i know, but it doesn't look good at all, and i'm sure this must be something really trivial (my css is currently a work in progress)

cheers

Comment: Only workaround  I found was using a fixed size for the dialog.

Comment: Yeah that did cross my mind, but I figured it would make the dialog non-responsive. this might not be as trivial as I thought. thanks for the reply

Comment: Use 'md-no-float' directive  <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone might be facing this problem, after much time I actually identified the problem:

```
md-input-container.md-icon-float {
    margin-top: -16px;
    transition: margin-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}
```

The only reason this only happens on the second input container in the dialog (the password field) is

```
md-dialog md-dialog-content:not([layout=row]) > *:first-child:not(.md-subheader) {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

So the first element in the md-dialog-content is not affected.

I'm perplexed as to the need for this transition (also referenced in issue [2991](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2991) on their repo anyway,

you can either insert an inline style on the md-input-container,

```
<md-input-container class="md-block md-icon-float md-icon-left" style="margin-top: 0;">
            <md-icon class="md-dark" arial-label="password">lock</md-icon>
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password">
            <div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>
</md-input-container>
```

or put each md-input-container element in a separate md-dialog-content (not sure if that's really the intended way to use md-dialog-content, so i went for the first solution)

Hope this helps someone, really small issue but can waste a lot of time for the nitpicky.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/alpha_purekar/pen/XdQEbe)
You may check it out

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Dialog Example" style="height:400px;width:400px;">
  <md-toolbar>
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <span flex></span>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
      <md-icon class="material-icons" aria-label="Close dialog">close</md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
   <form layout="row">  
     <span flex></span>
       <div layout="column">
         <div>
             <md-input-container>
               <label>UserName</label>
               <md-icon class="material-icons">person</md-icon>
               <input type="text" ng-model="somemodel" autocomplete="off">
             </md-input-container>
         </div>
         <div>
           <md-input-container>
               <label>UserName</label>
               <md-icon class="material-icons">lock</md-icon>
               <input type="password" ng-model="some">
             </md-input-container>
         </div>
         <md-button class="md-primary md-raised">
           Login
          </md-button> 
     </div>
   <span flex></span>

 </form>
```

Comment: I can definitely see that this works in the codepen, however I could not replicate it in my project, some problems arose with the icons going further up. maybe different material library versions? 

Regardless, thanks for the answer, it helped me reason some stuff out.